# In app purchasing with Microsoft Store in an Avalonia app

Tags: c#, windows-store, desktop-bridge, avaloniaui, microsoft-store

I'm trying to implement in app purchasing for an Avalonia application. I am using the Windows.Services.Store namespace. Whenever I try to use the GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync method to get information about the product, I get an error code in the ExtendedError of the StoreProductyQueryResult of 0x803F6107.

The application is an Avalonia app with a few projects. In addition to the application projects, there is a Windows Application Packaging Project.

- I have associated the app's packaging project with the store.
- I have created and had approved the store listing for the app.
- I have downloaded the app from the store and run it (this is supposed to get the license info I need to run the app in development according to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing)
- I have created and had approved a subscription addon.
- The packaging project is the startup project for the solution.
- I have deployed the app (right click the packaging project and press deploy) and then run using visual studio's standard Start Debugging.

Now, some code! Here is where I set up the store context - notice that I am using the Avalonia specific method for getting the window handle - I am unsure if this is the correct method in this context (though I have used this method in other parts of the application to get a handle to successfully launch windows printer driver settings windows)

```
            if (storeContext == null)
            {
                storeContext = StoreContext.GetDefault();
                _context = storeContext;
            }
            var window = Application.Current?.ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop ? desktop.MainWindow : null;
            var handle = window.PlatformImpl.Handle.Handle;
            WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(_context, handle);
```

Here is a function I am trying to use to check if the license is valid:

```
       public async Task<bool> CheckIfUserHasSubscriptionAsync()
        {
            StoreAppLicense appLicense = await _context.GetAppLicenseAsync();

            foreach (var addOnLicense in appLicense.AddOnLicenses)
            {
                StoreLicense license = addOnLicense.Value;
                if (license.SkuStoreId.StartsWith(_subscriptionStoreId))
                {
                    if (license.IsActive)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

When running this function, the length of AddOnLicenses is always 0 and the function goes straight to the return false.

Here is the function I am trying to use to get the list of products:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<StoreProduct>> GetSubscriptionProductsAsync()
        {
            StoreProductQueryResult result =
                await _context.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(new string[] { "Durable" });

            if (result.ExtendedError != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Something went wrong while getting the add-ons. " +
                    "ExtendedError:" + result.ExtendedError);
                return null;
            }

            return result.Products.Values;
        }
```

This function returns null with Extended error having a value of 0x803F6107.

Is anyone able to shed any light on this issue?

Comment: Error code [0x803F6107](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/error-codes-for-store-operations#in-app-purchase-error-codes): Something unexpected happened while processing the current operation. Please try to reproduce this problem in native UWP project so that we can confirm whether it is a problem with Store API.

Comment: OK - I've submited a test app to the store now. Hopefully, it will be approved quickly! I'll comment back here with updates soon hopefully.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT OK - so, I created a test UWP app and AddOn. Can confirm that is working just fine. One additional thing I did notice was that in the Avalonia app, the result of the call to GetAppLicenseAsync contains an empty SkuStoreId whereas the test app had this populated.

Comment: My suspicion is that the license from the store is not being retained somehow - how would I go about checking this?

Comment: Could you please check Add-ons status in the Partner Center? Is the status `In the store`? Can the subscription addon be successfully purchased in the test UWP project?

Comment: Yep, the addon's status for both the original app and the uwp test app is 'in the store'. Will try doing a uwp test purchase shortly.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Yep - can confirm purchasing subscription in the UWP app is working fine.

Comment: You can purchase the subscription successfully in native UWP, so this doesn't seem to have much to do with the UWP Store API and Partner Center, it could be a problem for Avalonia app.

Comment: I've gone a bit further overnight and created test apps with WPF + Packaging Project and Avalonia + Packaging Project. I've been able to successfully purchase a subscription in both these new test applications. With the exception of how the window handle is fetched (which varies platform by platform), the code is identical to the original project - so no issues with the code itself. I think the next thing I will try is removing the Packaging project from the original app and creating a new one + new Store App Registration. We will then see if this makes a difference.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT One difference I did observe when going through this process - when I deploy the original app the first time after installing and running the store version, I get a dialog in visual studio telling me that the app is already installed and that if I continue, it will remove the existing app and all it's settings. I don't get this with any of the test bed apps. Any thoughts on why this might be and whether this is something to do with the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - what finally solved it was going through the wapproj file and comparing line by line against the wapproj file of the Avalonia test project I had created. The original project had in a previous life been deployed using sideloading and had certificates etc. left in the config from that. I removed all of those and set it to use temporary store generated certificates instead. Then I downloaded the app from the store and ran it once before doing a deploy and run of the app from visual studio. This time, the store context was populated correctly and the errors are gone! Phew!